# Why would an auth token work for the explorer but not in a php app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on getting a fb auth working on my site. I have code in already to get the token and store it in a session variable. On a new page I have this:

```
echo $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
```

That puts out a long auth token that I can paste into this site :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

I paste the string in to the top Access token box and *can access* the fields that I asked permissions for in an earlier step.

Back to the code, I pass this line:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name','$_SESSION["facebook_access_token"]');
```

and get the following:

**Invalid OAuth access token.' in /{web root}/facebook/src/Facebook/Exceptions**

Now what the heck is going on here? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you select the appropriate application from the drop down in the API explorer? btw, you shoul not rely on that token, it will expire in an hour

Comment: I pulled down the correct application on the far upper right, is that what you mean? Also I will figure out how to extend the token separately; for now I'm just trying to figure out how to make the current token work on the php side

Comment: Use [url debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) to see what's fb is saying about this token.

Comment: Access Token Info  ||  
App ID {app id number}: {my app name}User ID  || 
 facebook id # : my name   ||  
User last installed this app via API v2.x  ||  
Issued Unknown  || 
Expires 1462521600 (in about an hour)   || 
Valid True  || 
Origin Unknown  || 
Scopes user_likes, email, public_profile  ||

Comment: Valid: True and Expires: in about an hour. Looks solid!